# QGIS forms and connected SQLite tables

Tags: qgis, sqlite, forms

I have a problem regarding QGIS forms for connected SQLite tables. The description is rather long, but needed in order to explain the issue.

While there are many tables, it is the connection between two of them that I cannot get to work when using forms. I have tried this with QGIS 3.28 and 3.32 (flatpak on RHEL9) with the same result.

The database contains industrial installations and their corresponding emissions of air pollutants.
The table "edb_pointsourcesubstance" contains emissions for different substances (see fig).
The second table is called "edb_pointsourcesubstance" and contains data on each point source (chimneys).
The tables are connected through the "source_id" in "edb_pointsourcesubstance", which is the "id" in "edb_pointsource" table.

[image: edb_pointsourcesubstance]

[image: edb_pointsource]

So, for instance, the "edb_pointsource" feature "source1" may have one or multiple substance emissions, defined in the "edb_pointsourcesubstance" table, each refered to through the "source_id".

To connect these tables, I have added a "relation" in the QGIS project properties:

```
edb_pointsource:id -> edb_pointsourcesubstance:source_id
```

Further, in the form for the edb_pointsourcesubstance table, I have set up the form for "source_id" to be a Value Relation pointing to edb_pointsource:id

[image: form for edb_pointsourcesubstance]

To test the setup, I switch both layers (tables) to edit-mode, then for the edb_pointsource I click the map to add a feature. The forms overall work ok. When adding the emission I will now get the form for the edb_pointsourcesubstance table.
After adding the feature, the "id" and "source_id" are listed as "auto-generated" in the feature tables.

In the form for edb_pointsource I have a box for the emissions, which opens the form for edb_pointsourcesubstance. This I managed by adding the QGIS-project-relation (see above) to the form.

[image: form for edb_pointsource]

[image: form for edb_pointsourcesubstance]

**Now the problem:**
When saving the layers, the source_id becomes "(0)" which I thought would be impossible since it should be an integer.

[image: edb_pointsourcesubstance after saving]

Adding more features will also only lead to each source_id being "(0)", so the number is not increased either.

**So, what have I missed or done wrong here?** Is it possible to solve so that it works the way I want? I should point out that the structure of the tables (and their connections) is not something I can change, since it is used in other systems and any changes would be very cumbersome.